# Does the Hagen–Poiseuille equation apply to inviscid core/entrance lengt regions?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, transport-phenomena

Does the Hagen–Poiseuille equation apply within the entrance length region of Incompressible, Newtonian fluid flow in a perfect tube?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Hagen–Poiseuille law is something that is used on a whole length of pipe, while your question sounds like it would be some local law that can be applied or checked at different points in the tube. This doesn't make much sense.

However, the answer should probably be "no". You need a sufficiently long pipe, cf. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hagen%E2%80%93Poiseuille_equation)

> The assumptions of the equation are that the fluid is incompressible and Newtonian; the flow is laminar through a pipe of constant circular cross-section that is *substantially longer than its diameter*; and there is no acceleration of fluid in the pipe. For velocities and pipe diameters above a threshold, actual fluid flow is not laminar but turbulent, leading to larger pressure drops than calculated by the Hagen–Poiseuille equation.

As the graphic you post shows, the parabolic velocity profile that can be used in the derivation of Hagen-Poiseuille has not developed fully in the entrance region.